# Combine generate series and count into one query

Tags: postgresql, subquery, generate-series

Postgres version 9.4.18, PostGIS Version 2.2.

I removed some of the details about the tables from this question because I doubt it's needed to answer the question.  I can add those details back if necessary.

**Desired result:**
I want a total count for each week of year and hour of day (0100 to 5223).  I'm able to successfully generate a series of 0100 to 5223 (actually up to 5300), and I'm able to get a total count for each week of year and hour of day individually, but i'm unable to combine the queries so that weeks of year/hours of day with a zero county still show up.  I want to combine the count result with the generate_series (and ideally divide that result by 30) to get something like below.

```
MM-DD  | count_not_zero | count_not_zero_divided_by_30
-------+----------------+----------------------------
0100  |       10        |  33.3
0101  |       0         |  0
0102  |       0         |  0
...
0123  |       0         |  0
0200  |       3         |  10
0201  |       10        |  33.3
...
5223  |       20        |  66.6
```

**Here are my individual queries that work...that I want to combine:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT f_woyhh(d::timestamp) as woyhh 
FROM generate_series(timestamp '2018-01-01', timestamp '2018-12-31', interval '1 hour') d 
GROUP BY woyhh
ORDER by woyhh asc;

SELECT dt, count(*) FROM 
(SELECT f_woyhh((time)::timestamp at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'america/chicago') 
AS dt, 
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM time) AS ctYear, count(*) 
AS ct 
FROM counties c 
INNER JOIN ltg_data d ON ST_contains(c.the_geom, d.ltg_geom) 
WHERE countyname = 'Milwaukee' AND state = 'WI' AND EXTRACT(YEAR from time) > '1987' GROUP BY dt, EXTRACT(YEAR from time)) 
AS count group by dt;
```

The result from the second query above is (and skips zero count dt, which I don't want):

```
dt  | count
-------+-------
0100  |    10      
0104  |    5       
0108  |    4
```

...

**Conclusion:**
I'm trying to combine the above working individual queries into a single query that provides a three a three column result--woyhh, count, and count divided by 30. And I want to include woyhh that have zero in the county, so that I have a complete set of woyhh.

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I'll be posting it tomorrow, but I wanted to put this on today so no one unnecessarily works on this question. I apologize for the formatting.

```
WITH CTE_Dates AS (SELECT DISTINCT f_woyhh(d::timestamp) as dt 
FROM generate_series(timestamp '2018-01-01', timestamp '2018-12-31', interval '1 hour') d), 
CTE_WeeklyHourlyCounts AS (SELECT dt, count(*) as ct 
FROM (SELECT f_woyhh((time)::timestamp at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'america/chicago') as dt, 
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM time) as ctYear, count(*) as ct 
FROM counties c 
INNER JOIN ltg_data d on ST_contains(c.the_geom, d.ltg_geom) 
WHERE countyname = 'Milwaukee' AND state = 'WI' AND EXTRACT(YEAR from time) > '1987' 
GROUP BY dt,
EXTRACT(YEAR from time)) as count group by dt), 
CTE_FullSTats AS (SELECT CTE_Dates.dt as dt, CAST(CTE_WeeklyHourlyCounts.ct as decimal) as ct 
FROM CTE_Dates LEFT JOIN CTE_WeeklyHourlyCounts ON CTE_WeeklyHourlyCounts.dt = CTE_Dates.dt 
GROUP BY CTE_Dates.dt, CTE_WeeklyHourlyCounts.ct, CTE_WeeklyHourlyCounts.dt) SELECT dt, COALESCE(ct, 0) 
AS count, round(((COALESCE(ct,0) * 100) / 30),0) as percent FROM CTE_FullStats 
GROUP BY dt, ct ORDER BY dt;
```